# How can I make my whole php safer?

Tags: php

I would like to know how to make a php file safer in general. I actually use mysqli, which is unfortunately not the newest version anymore, I know. I mysqli_escape_str...() all strings entered in input fields, too. But do you have some tips regarding the safety. I also use some ajax, if you need to know that.

Comment: Stop using mysqli_escape_string. You should be using parameterized queries instead of injecting variables directly into the query.

Comment: "How do I write code well?" is far *far* too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge subject and it depends what you're using at the moment but by the sounds of it I would suggest things like PDO instead of mysqli as this uses prepared statements. Its impossible for a SQL injection attack when using prepared statements properly. As for the AJAX you could ensure you are using CSRF tokens.

In general you can find a lot of the security risks here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet and some ways to mitigate them.

Comment: mysqli also support prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with queries in database, you have to make sure that there's no sql injection. Now because you already know `mysqli_escape_str`, I will suggest you something better : use [**prepared queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). 
Here's an example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
```